# Should I set up a developer account with dummy credentials?

Tags: paypal

I am a software developer working for a company that already does a lot of transactions online with PayPal. The developers who wrote the code for this have left and are not reachable.

I want to develop the company's PayPal code against a PayPal sandbox.
For this I need a Developer Account.
For this I need a PayPal business account.

My employer is reluctant to let me near their business account, to guard confidential revenue information, and to prevent developers inadvertently making live transactions, etc.

Should I just go ahead and register a dummy business account in order to set up a developer account?

Or is there some way to set up a developer account that does not have access to the main business account?

Thanks,

Alex

Comment: To create a developer account you do not need to have the business account information. You can create a dummy account if all you want to do is test

Comment: So if I sign up as a regular PayPal user, can I still test business account features such as recurring payments etc..?

Comment: Yes you can test these on the paypal test environment i.e. paypal sandbox

Comment: Create a developer on `developer.paypal.com`account with dummy credentials. Then go to `Applications -> Sandbox Accounts` and create preconfigured buyer and seller accounts